# JSON Path Syntax to merge two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a jSOn with two arrays. I would like to merge all items of both arrays into a single array. Is there a jSOn path syntax i could use to give the desired output?

**I have this:**

```
[
    "SomeArray",
    {
        "Branch1": {
            "Branch2": {
                "Branch3": {
                    "Array1": [
                        "Item1InArray1",
                        "Item2InArray1"
                    ],
                    "Array2": [
                        "Item1InArray2",
                        "Item2InArray2"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

**And want this output:** Its essentially two paths: `[1].Branch1.Branch2.Branch3.Array1` and `[1].Branch1.Branch2.Branch3.Array2`

```
[
    "Item1InArray1",
    "Item2InArray1",
    "Item1InArray2",
    "Item2InArray2"
]
```

Comment: Do you know exactly the structure and the keys of the JSON? Or it can have more brances and more arrays?

Comment: please add your code.

Comment: Calvin, i can have more branches and more arrays, i just wrote this as an example. I just need the coccept. Nina, i wont use any code, i just need the syntax such as [this](https://support.smartbear.com/alertsite/docs/monitors/api/endpoint/jsonpath.html)

Comment: Use loops to get to all the branches, and then combine the arrays with `concat()`.

Comment: @Joe there's no direct syntax for that you will have to implement your own logic.

Comment: do you want to take the path or independently all nested arrays?

Comment: @AZ_, so there's no `[1].Branch1.Branch2.Branch3..Array*` concept?

Comment: Use: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath

Answer (score 0):

This simple example shows how you can achieve this having a full string-based path.

```js
const arr = [
    {
        "Branch1": {
            "Branch2": {
                "Branch3": {
                    "Array1": [
                        "Item1InArray1",
                        "Item2InArray1"
                    ],
                    "Array2": [
                        "Item1InArray2",
                        "Item2InArray2"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
];

const paths = ["0.Branch1.Branch2.Branch3.Array1", "0.Branch1.Branch2.Branch3.Array2"];
const result = paths.map(path => path.split(".").reduce((unique, value) => unique[value], arr)).flat()

console.log(result)
```

Comment: when you know paths then what's the point of iterating through?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply get all nested arrays.

```js
const
    flat = item => item && typeof item === 'object'
        ? Array.isArray(item)
            ? item
            : Object.values(item).flatMap(flat)
        : [],
    data = ["SomeArray", { Branch1: { Branch2: { Branch3: { Array1: ["Item1InArray1", "Item2InArray1"], Array2: ["Item1InArray2", "Item2InArray2"] } } } }],
    items = data.flatMap(flat);

console.log(items);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    {
        "Branch1": {
            "Branch2": {
                "Branch3": {
                    "Array1": [
                        "Item1InArray1",
                        "Item2InArray1"
                    ],
                    "Array2": [
                        "Item1InArray2",
                        "Item2InArray2"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
]

let newArray = array1.reduce((main, curr)=> main.concat(curr.Branch1.Branch2.Array1, curr.Branch1.Branch2.Array1),[])
```